# Drag and drop stored procedure on .dbml file(VS 2010) and upon saving it creates another designer1.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, dbml

In my project, I have a data-access layer that contains .dbml file(named test.dbml) used to drag and drop stored procedures and tables. Two days ago when I drag and drop the stored procedure onto my test.dbml file. Upon saving it creates another test.designer1.cs class and the old test.designer.cs class remains unchanged. I use visual studio 2010 and it was very weird for me. I've checked my rights on the folder which contains my project but all seems ok because two days earlier it was working fine and suddenly it happened. I Google it but find no solution so I decided to write this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At-last i've solved it myself.........and i am going to share it that what i have done. my dbml file name was test.dbml having test.dbml.layout and test.designer.cs files now the problem was when ever i drag and drop stored procedure or table it creates a new designer file with name test.desginer1.cs and when i build data-ccess layer it gives me hell of errors my brain was out at that time and with angry face i delete the test.designer.cs (original file) from the solution after that there was only one file test.designer1.cs which i renamed from test.designer1.cs to test.designer.cs and build data-access layer and i was wondered that it was build successfully. this solve my problem however there are other points as well to keep in mind

1. make sure your dbml files should not be read-only
2. you have full access to write file on disk (means check your rights on directory where your solution is placed)